# Stack navigator causes background color to change in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I am making an app in React Native. I had made one of the screens and decided to add a stack navigator for navigation. However, when I added the stack navigator, the background color of the screen changed to this light grey. I want it to go back to default white. Also, before you ask, no, adding `backgroundColor: 'white'` to the css of the view doesn't work. For some reason it only makes half of the screen white and the other half stays grey. How can I make the screen background color go back to default white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cardStyle`
Style object for the card in stack. You can provide a custom background color to use instead of the default background here.

You can also specify `{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }` to make the previous screen visible underneath (for transparent modals). This is useful to implement things like modal dialogs. You should also specify `mode: 'modal'` in the stack view config when using a transparent background so previous screens aren't detached and stay visible underneath.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried it and it wasn't working, then I noticed I had it applied to the wrong screen.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, try change the card background color of your navigation container, it will look like this.

```js
<NavigationContainer theme={{colors: {background: '#63C2D1'}}}>
   <YourStack/>
</NavigationContainer>
```

now when your change your screens it will show the background-color.